# Add XML outline to Xtext DSL IDE

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, dsl, xtext

I have DSL IDE generated by xtext 2.8.4. It works OK. Due to different reason I have to implement a few editors for different kind of file. I've easy added XML editor with syntax coloring. Also I need to outline view for XML. If I not mistake I have to implement something like this

```
public class XMLOutlineTreeProvider implements IOutlineTreeStructureProvider, IOutlineTreeProvider, IOutlineTreeProvider.Cancelable {}
```

Also Eclipse platform itself has XML outline implementation. Can I reuse this implementaion in xtext project?
I'm sure that there is ready to use implementation for this task, but I could find it. The next question I could not find out how register my implementaion in XText core

Any advises appreciated

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it's more effort to reuse the existing outline implementation than to implement a few methods on your own. In fact, you just have to provide a label, an icon path and a list of children for your xml nodes.

It would look like this in principle (code is Xtend):

```
def _createChildren(IOutlineNode parentNode, Element element) {
    element.children.forEach [
        createNode(parentNode, it);
    ]
}
```

The label provider:

```
def text(Element ele) {
    return ele.name
}

def text(Attribute attr) {
    attr.name + '=' + attr.value 
}

def image(Element ele) {
    'element.gif'
}
```

The domain model example or the arithmetics example do implement a simple outline. You may want to look into these.

Reusing the existing stuff is more cumbersome since you'd have to adapt the Xtext model based on EMF to the internal model that the XML outline expects.

Comment: I see you point. Thanks. But I don't understand can I register in xtext (AbstractPSLUiModule) two or more implementation of OutlineTreeProvider classes. One if them that provides implementation of my DSL has been already registered. Seems to me I should implement complicated logic for this purposes

Comment: From other hands that DSL IDE that was built based on XTEXT will support a few kind of languages. As it has done in professional IDE. In IDEA I can open different kind of file in see its structure

Comment: It's possible to have more than one outline tree provider but that would not work with a simple binding. In that case, you'd need some notion of modes or another implementation of the outline page. Please refer to the standard JFace APIs for the outline page or take a look at the Xbase outline where different filters and modes can be applied.